# creating letsencrypt certificate fails

Tags: apache, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

i'm on ubuntu 17.10 . looks like installed certbot successfully.
when i run

```
sudo certbot --apache -d mywebsite.com -d www.mywebsite.com
```

i get an error:

```
root@servername:~# sudo certbot --apache -d mywebsite.ca -d www.mywebsite.ca
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mywebsite.ca
http-01 challenge for www.mywebsite.ca
Enabled Apache rewrite module
Error while running apache2ctl graceful.
httpd not running, trying to start
Action 'graceful' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Any idea?
obviously apache is not running, but that's ok, i'm using nginx, so i don't need apache. or do i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running nginx server, use the nginx plugin (not apache):

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d mywebsite.com -d www.mywebsite.com
```